# How can I get an uniform, integer date format in R?

Tags: r, date, formatting

I am using a dataset that has two different types of dates in a column: they could be either YYYYMMDD or MM/DD/YYYY (M/D/YYYY if single digit month and/or year).

I want to put all dates into the first format. str(dataset) tells me that this column in formatted in character. When I try to change the format it always returns NA for the MM/DD/YYYY dates. The result should be in integer and YYYYMMDD.

Can anyone help me to fix this in R? Would be highly appreciated!

I tried to check for the format and then convert it but there is some mistake such that I arrive at NA.

Comment: Check `anytime::anydate`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `lubridate::parse_date_time` to change dates in different format to one standard format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) and in `Date` class. I would suggest to keep dates in this format as date class because it is easier to manipulate them or do any transformation.

However, to answer your question we can change them to integer class using `format`.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, 
                 date = c("20190605", "5/23/2020", "20201105", "11/11/2018"))

df$new_date <- as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(df$date, c("Ymd", "mdy")))
df$new_date2 <- as.integer(format(df$new_date, "%Y%m%d"))
df

#  id       date   new_date new_date2
#1  1   20190605 2019-06-05  20190605
#2  2  5/23/2020 2020-05-23  20200523
#3  3   20201105 2020-11-05  20201105
#4  4 11/11/2018 2018-11-11  20181111

str(df)

# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ id       : int  1 2 3 4
# $ date     : chr  "20190605" "5/23/2020" "20201105" "11/11/2018"
# $ new_date : Date, format: "2019-06-05" "2020-05-23" "2020-11-05" "2018-11-11"
# $ new_date2: int  20190605 20200523 20201105 20181111
```

`date` column is the original date, `new_date` is of type `Date` in standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format whereas `new_date2` is of type `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Base R** `chardates2int` is a function that converts character string dates to integers.  It tries each of the formats specified in fmt in turn on each element of the character vector input returning an integer vector.  No packages are used.

It applies `as.Date` using `tryFormats=` to each element and then converts the resulting list to a vector using `c.Date`, formats it to a character string yyyymmdd and then converts that to integer.

```
chardates2int <- function(x, fmt = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y%m%d")) {
  x |>
    lapply(as.Date, tryFormats = fmt) |>
    do.call("c", args = _) |>
    format("%Y%m%d") |>
    as.integer()
}

# test
x <- c("20001230", "11/22/2001", "11/22/2001", "20001230")
chardates2int(x)
## [1] 20001230 20011122 20011122 20001230
```

**2) anydate** As mentioned in the comments we can make use of `anydate` in the anytime package.

```
library(anytime)

chardates2int2 <- function(x) {
  x |>
    anydate() |>
    format("%Y%m%d") |>
    as.integer()
}

# test
x <- c("20001230", "11/22/2001", "11/22/2001", "20001230")
chardates2int2(x)
## [1] 20001230 20011122 20011122 20001230
```

**3) sub** Another possibility is to use character manipulation to put the mm/dd/yyyy dates into yyyymmdd form and then use `as.integer`.  No packages are used.

```
chardates2int3 <- function(x) {
  sub("(..)/(..)/(....)", "\\3\\1\\2", x) |> as.integer()
}

# test
x <- c("20001230", "11/22/2001", "11/22/2001", "20001230")
chardates2int3(x)
## [1] 20001230 20011122 20011122 20001230
```